# Local undefined 404 when doing API call

Tags: javascript, html

This project is using the cocktail api to search for a specific ingredient (think gin or vodka) and then return all the drinks that contain the ingredient. I was able to get the results to display, but I wanted the thumbnail pic of the drink (included in the api as `strDrinkThumb`). When I try to get the pictures to display I get the follow error:

```
GET http://local/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
  });

let ingredients = document.getElementById('ingredients');
let searchTerm= document.getElementById('search-Bar');
let searchBtn = document.getElementById('searchBtn');
let drinkInfo = document.getElementById('drinkInfo');
let ingredientList = []


searchBtn.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
    const searchString = searchTerm.value.toLowerCase();
    fetch(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=${searchString}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((filteredIngredients) => {
        displayIngredient(filteredIngredients.drinks);
        })
    .catch((error) => {
       
     });    
        
});



function displayIngredient(drinkData){

    const ingredients = [];

   //maps over array and makes new array
  drinkInfo.innerHTML =  drinkData.map( ({strDrink}) => { //destructuring
      //use backticks and html  
      return` <div> //use backticks and html
        <div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">${strDrink} </h5>
         
          <img src="${drinkData.strDrinkThumb}"/>
       
        </div></div>
        `; //use backticks and html
         }).join('');
        
    drinkInfo.appendChild(drinkInfo);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Cocktail App</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    
  
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <input type="text" id="search-Bar" placeholder="Enter main ingredient..."/>
        <button id="searchBtn">search</button>
    </header>
    <div class="drinkInfo" id="drinkInfo">
      
          </div>


    </div>
</div>
 </div>
    </div>
</div>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="./extrafile.js"></script>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Are you assuming everyone knows what "cocktail api" is? replace `{strDrink}` with `{strDrink, strDrinkThumb}` and `drinkData.strDrinkThumb` with `strDrinkThumb`

Answer (score -1):

In `drinkData.map` function you are only pulling `strDrink` value from the object, you need also get `strDrinkThumb`

Then you are trying get `strDrinkThumb` from `drinkData` which is an array, not an object.

Try this:

```
  drinkInfo.innerHTML =  drinkData.map( ({strDrink, strDrinkThumb}) => { //destructuring
      //use backticks and html  
      return` <div> //use backticks and html
        <div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">${strDrink} </h5>
         
          <img src="${strDrinkThumb}"/>
       
        </div></div>
        `; //use backticks and html
         }).join('');
```